# Move navigation bar items back to top on extended Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have increased the height of the Navigation Bar, but now my navigation bar items (back button and rightbar button) appear on the bottom of the bar. I have multiple TVCs embeded in Navigation Controller. How can I set navigation bar items back to their original position to the top to be able to add subview underneath them?

```
CGFloat navBarHeight = 100.0f;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, navBarHeight);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];
```

Thanks.